# Difference between TEXT mode and ASCII mode in File transfer through FTP?

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, file-transfer, winscp

I am facing a strange issue when transferring file through WinSCP FTP tool.
I downloaded a shell script file from server and made some minor modification. Uploaded this file on same UNIX server through WinSCP Tool.

When I select **Transfer settings as Binary**, Shell script doesn't work properly and failed. Even generated log file didn't open.

When I select **Transfer settings as TEXT** it worked properly.

Also, when I set **Transfer settings as ASCII** in File transfer through FTP command in Terminal, even it didn't work.

On the basis of above issues, I have below concerns:

- Difference between **TEXT** mode transfer and **ASCII** mode
  transfer?
- Difference between transferring file through FTP command
  via Terminal and using FTP tool like WinSCP, FileZilla, FireFTP?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with translation between Newlines, Carriage Returns and NL/CR combinations. i.e. Transfering a text file from a DOS machine to a UNIX machine, ASCII mode will to the proper translation, and "TEXT" mode (which I believe is really "binary" mode) will just transfer as-is, with no translation.

Comment: "Binary" and "Text" are two different modes as these two are options listed in Transfer settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between "text" and "ascii" transfer mode. These are just two names that are used interchangeably for the same mode.

There should be no difference between the text/ascii mode in GUI FTP clients and the Windows command-line FTP client.

Though the can be some implementation detail that might make a difference for a particular server.